# Python Bokehでブラウザに表示せずに、グラフの保存だけしたい

Tags: python, bokeh

## 環境

- Python 3.6
- bokeh 0.13.0

## やりたいこと

Bokehというライブラリで、グラフを表示しています。

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
output_file("test.html")
p = figure()
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)
show(p)
```

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/installation.html

## 質問

show関数を実行すると、ブラウザが起動してそこにグラフが表示されます。
HTMLファイルは生成したいけど、ブラウザを起動させたくないときは、どのように設定すればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save(p)`だと思います。

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
output_file("test.html")
p = figure()
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)
save(p)
```

Comment: `boke.io.save`をimportして、実現できました。
https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.save